# Neverending loading instead of NotFoundPage

Tags: reactjs

In my app I created a NotFound component and the appropriate NotFound route. When I request an address like `locahost:3000/dfsdfdummyaddress` or `locahost:3000/post/dfsdfdummyaddress`, the NotFound page displays like it should to. But if I request an address which looks like `localhost:3000/profile/sdgsdfdummyaddress` (with address to `profile`), I get only neverending loading.
What am I doing wrong?

The file with routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Register from '../auth/Register';
import Login from '../auth/Login';
import Alert from '../layout/Alert';
import Dashboard from '../dashboard/Dashboard';
import CreateProfile from '../profile-forms/CreateProfile';
import EditProfile from '../profile-forms/EditProfile';
import AddExperience from '../profile-forms/AddExperience';
import AddEducation from '../profile-forms/AddEducation';
import Profiles from '../profiles/Profiles';
import Profile from '../profile/Profile';
import Posts from '../posts/Posts';
import Post from '../post/Post';
import NotFound from '../layout/NotFound';
import PrivateRoute from '../routing/PrivateRoute';

const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <section className="container">
          <Alert />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
                <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                <Route exact path='/profiles' component={Profiles} />
                <Route exact path='/profile/:id' component={Profile} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/create-profile' component={CreateProfile} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/edit-profile' component={EditProfile} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/add-experience' component={AddExperience} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/add-education' component={AddEducation} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/posts' component={Posts} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/posts/:id' component={Post} />
                <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
        </section>
    );
}

export default Routes;
```

The NotFound page:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

const NotFound = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className='x-large text-primary'>
        <i className='fas fa-exclamation-triangle' /> Page Not Found
      </h1>
      <p className='large'>Sorry, this page does not exist</p>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default NotFound;
```

The App.jsx file:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Landing from './components/layout/Landing';
import Routes from './components/routing/Routes';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import { loadUser } from './actions/auth';
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken';

if (localStorage.token) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
     store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
            <Route component={Routes} />
          </Switch>
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why?

Your sample route matches `/profile/:id`.

I'm assuming you're expecting react-router to know that "sdgsdfdummyaddress" is not legitimate which it cannot do for you so react-router is behaving as expected.

The "post" version does not match because your route is plural (`/posts/:id`).

#### Solutions

There are a few strategies you can use to solve this.

One would be to redirect to a dedicated "not found" route if the ID cannot be found.

Another would be to display the same "not found" component from within your `Profile` component if the ID is not found.